# apply function to groups of rows of equal size in data frames

Tags: r

I have a data-frame of y and x values. The dimensions of the data-frame are 10000 rows and 2 columns. The 10000 rows refer to 500 samples, each with 20 y and x values.

How can I apply a function on each sample (each group of 20 rows) and store the results in a separate 500-row data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `tapply` for that. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(sample = rep(1:500, each = 20), values = rnorm(10000))
matrix(tapply(df$values, df$sample, mean))
```